# How can I disable JSCS in Web Essentials for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, web-essentials, jscs

How might I disable JSCS in the latest version of Web Essentials for Visual Studio 2013?

I was unable to find a relevant option in the menu.

I tried setting the JSCS configuration to ignore all files. This caused it to occasionally generate messages that wouldn't leave my Error List panel until I cleaned the solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Web Essentials 2013 for Update 4 supports a `.weignore` file where you can disable JSCS, or other linters and compilers, independently of each other.

See https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/pull/1250

Create a `.weignore` file and add the following line:

```
**\*.js jscs
```

That's a `tab` character between the `*.js` and the `jscs` parts of the line.

You can create a global `.weignore` file in your user folder (C:\Users\username), or in your project or solution folder.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work for me (restarting VS did not help either).

Answer (score 15):

I've found this settings file seems to quiet it down quite a bit. You can find this in Web Essentials > Edit Global JSCS settings.

```
{
    "requireCurlyBraces": ["if"],

    "excludeFiles": ["**"],
    "validateJSDoc": {
        "checkParamNames": true,
        "requireParamTypes": true
    }
}
```

It essentially disables JSCS while keeping JSHint open. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'd been trying to use a single `*`, as in `"excludeFiles": ["*"]`. Just adding the second asterisk solves my primary JSCS headache.

Comment: It seems as if correctly setting `excludeFiles` is sufficient. Should this be the case?

Comment: You know what, it is sufficient. I found the best solution (which didn't involve killing all the options) from a coworker after I posted here. At least in my project, "\*\*" wasn't cutting it. We had to go "Scripts/\*\*" or something along those lines. I'll update the post when I get back to the office and see what we actually had.

Comment: I found that `"excludeFiles": ["/**"],'` disabled the checking for all files. Note the leading forward slash. It seems that this path is being interpreted as a full path rather than a relative path. I was able to target specific folders as well but you have to specify it assuming a full path e.g. `"/**/Scripts/*.js"`. I suspect you could research node file globbing documentation to really understand the options.

Comment: I was encountering the same problem and used Bryan and Martin's comment solution to make it work.  Change it to "excludeFiles": ["/**"] which stops it from hitting any of the JS files.

Comment: I've added ""excludeFiles": ["/**"]" and still get JSCS messages. Any ideas? VS 2013 Update 4.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file .jscsrc in your project-root (e.g. via the command line: echo x > .jscsrc).
Then use the following content:

```
{
    "excludeFiles": ["**"]
}
```

I just like to keep all the project-settings together and avoid global settings that need to be synchronized between developers manually.